# Can Sending All Possible Otp Codes Within 1 Second Bypass Server Protections?

Tags: brute-force, one-time-password, totp

I'm exploring the security implications of OTP (One-Time Password) authentication and wondering about the effectiveness of server-side protections against brute force attacks.

If an attacker attempts to send all possible OTP codes within a 1-second timeframe, is there a chance that the server could accept the correct one and grant the attacker access?

What are recommended strategies or technologies to prevent such rapid-fire OTP brute force attacks and ensure robust security?

Comment: Rate-limiting appears to be the most obvious protection. Next being a failure-limit.

Comment: I googled "brute force TOTP" and got quite a few hits including the links above. Please make sure that you look up this kind of thing.